# How to dispatch event from application to module in flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, module

Is there a way how modules can listen to parent application event? My current solution that works is:

```
private function directoryRemoteObject_saveCompany_resultHandler(e:ResultEvent):void
{
  this.directoryModuleLoader.child.dispatchEvent(new CompanyEvent(CompanyEvent.COMPANY_SAVED, e.result as int));
}
```

this means that I need to dispatch event for every module. Isn't there better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to dispatch event from application context

```
Application.application.dispatchEvent(new Event("Test"));
```

Use below code to listen event from module

```
Application.application.addEventListener("Test",function1);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just  adding a listener?

```
        parentApplication.addEventListener( ...)
```

Comment: I want modules to listen for events, not parentApplication.

Comment: This would be called from a module, hence you would be listenning from the module to events dispatched by the parent application.
Sounds close?

Comment: You need to trigger the event within the application and place the addListener() in the module.
The example from Nirmal will hopefully shed some light.